# How to calculate the derivative of cos(x) in Calculus Made Easy

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

in [Chapter 15](http://calculusmadeeasy.org/15.html) of Calculus Made Easy, the author proves the derivative of $ cos(\theta) $:

[image]

I'm unable to understand what did he do in the following step:

$$ dy = d(sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)) = cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)) * d(-\theta) $$

Comment: it's the chain rule:  $\dfrac d{dx}\sin(f(x))=\cos(f(x))\dfrac d{dx}f(x)$ with $f(x)=\dfrac\pi2-\theta $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You copy what the author wrote as  $y= cos(\pi/2- \theta)\times d(-\theta)$
but then ask about $y= cos(\pi/2- \theta) -d(-\theta)$

Do you see that those are *not* the same?

Perhaps it would have easier to see if it had been written $y= cos(\pi/2- \theta)\times d(\pi/2-\theta)$.  Of course since $\pi/2$ is a constant, $d(\pi/2-\theta)= d(-\theta)$

Comment: The subtraction was a typing error while writing the question. Thank you, the shortcut writing $ d(-\theta) $ directly confused me.

Answer (score 1):

It's the chain rule:  $\dfrac d{dx}\sin(f(x))=\cos(f(x))\dfrac d{dx}f(x),$ with $f(x)=\dfrac\pi2-\theta $